# Hacer un Rango de fechas en Español usando Jquery Ui datepicker y php

Tags: php, date, jquery-datepicker

Estoy tratando de guardar en un array un rango de fechas definidas por el usuario a través de 2 datepickers traducidos al español, pero al hacer `strtotime()` a las fechas me toma el mes como día y viceversa.

Ejemplo:

Elijo `27/05/2017` y al haber hecho a esa fecha claro que no la reconoce como tal al ser el mes `27`

Si elijo `01/05/2017` en el array aparece como `05/01/2017`
aqui va la funcion que uso para tomar los datos de los input y la funcion que uso para guardar los datos en el array.

```
function tomafechas(){
if(isset($_POST['repS'])){      
    $fechaD = $_POST['txtdesde'];
    $fechaH = $_POST['txthasta'];
    $fechaArray = generafechas($fechaD,$fechaH);
}

function generafechas($date1,$date2){
    $fecharray = array();
    if (is_string($date1) === true){            
        $date1 = strftime("%d-%m-%Y",strtotime($date1));            
    }
    if (is_string($date2) === true){            
        $date2 = strftime("%d-%m-%Y",strtotime($date2));            
    }
    do {
        $fecharray[] = date("m-d-Y", $date1);
         $date1 = strtotime("+1 day", $date1);  
    } while($date1 <= $date2);
return $fecharray;
}
```

**PD:** Ya he puesto como formato de fecha local el español con `setLocale(LC_TIME,'spanish')` en el archivo en el que estoy usando estas funciones.

Comment: Añadiendo un poco más, mi sugerencia seria que no guardes las fechas en un formato local. Por que siempre va a haber pedos con los servidores. Intenta guardarla en un formato ISO, de tal forma que siempre se pueda recuperar tanto en JS (front) y Back (PHP,Node,JAVA). Así no tendrás que hacer conversiones extrañas,  el datepicker de JqueryUi lo soporta: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde PHP 5.4 puedes usar el método estático [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Es como un `strtotime` pero en vez de devolver un número devuelve un objeto del tipo [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) con el cual puedes operar ya sea devolviendo una cadena formateada o comparando con otro `DateTime`. Pero, por encima de todo, acepta como primer parámetro una cadena de formato, lo cual a diferencia de `strtotime` te permite discriminar en forma más fina la interpretación del segundo parámetro.

En tu caso se usaría más o menos asi:

```
function generafechas($date1,$date2){
    $fecharray = array();
    if (is_string($date1) === true){            
        $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date1);
    }
    if (is_string($date2) === true){            
       $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date2);          
    }
    do {
        $fecharray[] = $date1->format('m-d-Y');
        // Añado un día
        $date1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));  
    } while($date1 <= $date2);
    return $fecharray;
}
```

Comment: Hola lo hice de esa manera y funcionó muy bien, pero como puedo hacer para que `$date1->format('m-F-Y')` me arroje el nombre del mes en español? necesito tenerlo porque las fechas en la base de datos están ingresadas en Varchar de esta forma Ejemplo "07 de Junio del 2016"'

Comment: PD: yo no lo hice así o me hubiera ahorrado muchísimo trabajo, estoy mejorando un sistema antiguo y no tengo acceso a modificar los datos